# Firefox Highcharts is not showing up but it's all OK in Chrome and Edge

Tags: angular, firefox, highcharts, angular-highcharts

The following pie chart shows up in Chrome and Edge but not in Firefox (latest vers 88).

I'm trying to horizontally align two divs. On the left a form and on the right a chart.

I omit all the details inside the form html because I think they're not relevant.

I've also tried with `float:left` vs `float:none;` or `float: right` instead of `display: inline-block`

```
  <div  style="display: inline-block;vertical-align:top;">
  <h2>{{title}}</h2>
  <form [formGroup]="rangeFormGroup">  
    <div>  
      <mat-form-field appearance="fill">  
      </mat-form-field> 
    </div>  
    <div>
      <mat-form-field appearance="fill">
      </mat-form-field> 
      <br>
      <mat-form-field appearance="fill">
      </mat-form-field> 
    </div>
  </form>
</div>
<div style="display: inline-block;height: 500px;width: 500px;">
  <highcharts-chart
    [Highcharts]="Highcharts"
    [constructorType]="chartConstructor"
    [options]="chartOptions[0]"
    [(update)]="updateFlag"
    [oneToOne]="oneToOneFlag"
    [runOutsideAngular]="runOutsideAngular"
  ></highcharts-chart>
</div>
```

This is what I see from chrome

[image]

and from firefox

[image]

When I build I receive a warning saying

```
Warning: F:\myapp\src\app\app.component.ts depends on 'highcharts'. CommonJS or AMD dependencies can cause optimization bailouts.
For more info see: https://angular.io/guide/build#configuring-commonjs-dependencies
```

but maybe this is also not the cause (or why should it affect only firefox?)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Problem was in the app.component.ts.

Firefox wants the height set in the chart options, like below

```
  options: Highcharts.Options[] = [{
    chart: {
      plotBackgroundColor: 'white',
      plotBorderWidth: undefined,
      plotShadow: false,
      type: 'pie',
      height: 500,  // FIREFOX WANTS THIS !!!
    },
    credits: {
      enabled: false
```

Issue solved, however, on a side note, one could also consider the [advanced pie](https://swimlane.gitbook.io/ngx-charts/examples/pie-charts/advanced-pie-chart)  from ngx-charts (that should be easily integrable inside any Angular component)